# Array of objects transformation to get count of each property in the array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have an array of objects coming from a database that is stored in an angular scope variable. The array format :

```
$scope.Divisions = [
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 2" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 3" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 5" },

    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },
    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN4", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },

    { "Division": "Div3", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div3 KPI 7" },

    { "Division": "Div4", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div4 KPI 7" },
]
```

The transformed array I need is to get **distinct** Data Name and **distinct** KPI count for each Division in the below format:

```
[

    ['Div1', 3, 5],
    ['Div2', 2, 1],
    ['Div3', 1, 1],
    ['Div4', 1, 1]
  ]
```

Comment: this seems like a loop to me -- did you try that?  Did you have an issue with it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: You probably want `for..in`, but any loop could be used.

Comment: How the 2nd entry is calculated? ['Div1', 3, 5]

Comment: 3 unique Data Names, 5 unique KPI

Comment: Don't mind, but this is pure logic building, you should do it yourself. 
If this is done by something else, then it is not helping, it is like doing your job. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of one way to do it, using reduce and map (slower than loops due to function calls but very expressive & functional style and for small arrays, you will never notice the performance difference):

In essence:

- create constants for the keys/properties to count `const a = "Data Name"; const b = "KPI";`
- generate an empty object and populate it by looping over the items in the input array (using reduce here or for loop below)
- each time check if the property of the Division is already present in the object (e.g. check if the object has the prop/key "Div1" first etc.)
- if it is not present, add this item to the object with that property and convert the item[a] and item[b] to single item arrays. (where a and b are defined above)
- if it is already present, then push on to item[a] and item[b] (only if the value is not in the array by checking that `.indexOf() == -1` ).
- convert this Object to an array of values
- map over the array (with map here or for loop below) and convert to `[item.Division, item[a].length, item[b].length]`

```js
const Divisions = [
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 2" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 3" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 5" },
    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },
    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN4", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },
    { "Division": "Div3", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div3 KPI 7" },
    { "Division": "Div4", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div4 KPI 7" },
];

const a = "Data Name";
const b = "KPI";
const tempOutput = Divisions.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
  
  if (aggObj[item.Division]){
    if (aggObj[item.Division][a].indexOf(item[a]) == -1 ){
      aggObj[item.Division][a].push(item[a]);
    }
    if (aggObj[item.Division][b].indexOf(item[b]) == -1 ){
      aggObj[item.Division][b].push(item[b]);
    }
  }
  else {
    aggObj[item.Division] = item;
    aggObj[item.Division][a] = [item[a]];
    aggObj[item.Division][b] = [item[b]];
  }
  
  return aggObj;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(tempOutput).map(item => {  
  return [item.Division, item[a].length, item[b].length];
});

//console.log(tempOutput)
console.log(output)
```

Output:

```js
[
  ["Div1", 3, 5],
  ["Div2", 2, 1],
  ["Div3", 1, 1],
  ["Div4", 1, 1]
]
```

Example of another way to do it, using for loop (faster, usually easier if coming from another language etc.):

```js
const Divisions = [
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 2" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 3" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 5" },
    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },
    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN4", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },
    { "Division": "Div3", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div3 KPI 7" },
    { "Division": "Div4", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div4 KPI 7" },
];

const a = "Data Name";
const b = "KPI";
const aggObj = {};

for (let item of Divisions){
  
  if (aggObj[item.Division]){
    if (aggObj[item.Division][a].indexOf(item[a]) == -1 ){
      aggObj[item.Division][a].push(item[a]);
    }
    if (aggObj[item.Division][b].indexOf(item[b]) == -1 ){
      aggObj[item.Division][b].push(item[b]);
    }
  }
  else {
    aggObj[item.Division] = item;
    aggObj[item.Division][a] = [item[a]];
    aggObj[item.Division][b] = [item[b]];
  }

}

const tempOutput = Object.values(aggObj);
const output = [];
for (let item of tempOutput){  
  output.push([item.Division, item[a].length, item[b].length]);
}

//console.log(tempOutput)
console.log(output)
```

Output:

```js
[
  ["Div1", 3, 5],
  ["Div2", 2, 1],
  ["Div3", 1, 1],
  ["Div4", 1, 1]
]
```

Comment: While reduce works, it seems really advanced for someone who does not even know how to make a loop.  I'd suggest at least some explanation of how this works or an additional example of using a loop.  Maybe also someting about why you think this is better than a loop.  (Which I personally don't think).

Comment: The OP's profile says he has 4 years professional experience and a CS degree, so I don't want to assume he cannot write a for-loop. The difference between reduce and a for loop is basically only 2 lines (I added for loop now too). For loop will always be faster because you don't need function calls, but reduce is expressive. If performance isn't an issue, I prefer reduce, but that's just my preference.

Comment: I also swapped out the ``.map()`` for a for loop too in the second example. I also added some bullet points to explain the approach.

Comment: excellent updates alex!  -- just a note about performance.  map/reduce was designed to be performant when you had clusters of machines solving big problems.  That is why it does not work well on a problem like this -- cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Comment: @Hogan that is not the reason it is slower.  Function call and object initialization is the reason it is slower.  For example, I guarantee you my code using Set()s will be faster, even with a chain of 10 map/reduces, than this code here no matter how much you tweak it. The function call overhead of reduce will be negligible at worst. As to the advantage of using Map/Reduce, when I can express data (model) transformations, and data shape transformations as a chain of simple object comprehensions, the outcome will almost always be more concise than large blocks of branching logic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Hogan. Although, the article you linked to said: "It is inspired by the Map (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function) ) and Reduce (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function) ) functions commonly used in functional programming,[5] although their purpose in the MapReduce framework is not the same as in their original forms" - so it didn't seem to me as if the JavaScript array methods, map and reduce, are designed for clusters/distributed computing, per see? (rather primarily for functional programming style?)

Comment: @AlexL what he said has truth to it.  The concept was popularized by big data, esp. when Google published their data processing optimization by use of Map Reduce to enable moving large amounts of data locally to be transformed before being transferred, where network transfers and I/O were the main bottleneck.  It also simplified the way data transformations were represented and done, and so it was a highly productive pattern.  He comes from a db admin background, so that's probably where he's coming from.

Comment: Ok, I am learning a lot today :) - So map, reduce etc. (higher order array methods) are slower than for loops because of function calls and object initialization. Also map & reduce were developed with functional style and parallel computing in mind (I assume because we want pure functions, no side effects etc.)? - I don't fully understand how reduce can be parallelized when the aggregator is an object and we check if the property is already present etc.? (But perhaps that's an example of what you don't do as it would not be pure?) Map is easy to think about being parallelized.

Comment: There's also some things like native array optimizations, where they can be an order of magnitude more performant.  Depends on the JS engine.

Comment: Gotchya, so V8 might have optimized ``.map()`` to be faster than for loops as long as it is an array of all small integers etc.? https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds (But SpiderMonkey might not have optimized it and so it might be slower than for loops there etc.?)

Comment: Or do you mean like the typed arrays like Int8Array() etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Use an object map with key: [Division] to track Divisions.  Use Set()s to track duplicates.  Map to .size() to get counts.
Detailed commented code at bottom.

```js
Divisions = [
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 2" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 3" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN1", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 1" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN2", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 4" },
    { "Division": "Div1", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div1 KPI 5" },

    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },
    { "Division": "Div2", "Data Name": "DN4", "KPI": "Div2 KPI 6" },

    { "Division": "Div3", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div3 KPI 7" },

    { "Division": "Div4", "Data Name": "DN3", "KPI": "Div4 KPI 7" },
]

console.log(
 Object.values(
  Divisions.reduce((acc,{Division,['Data Name']:Name,KPI}) => {
    const [,Names,KPIs] = 
      acc[Division] = acc[Division] || [Division,new Set(),new Set()]
    Names.add(Name)
    KPIs.add(KPI)
    return acc
  },{})
 ).map(([div,names,kpis])=>([div,names.size,kpis.size]))
)
```

```js
   // unwrap object map to values
   Object.values(
    // iterate over Divisions objects and create object map key: [Division] to track Divisions
    Divisions.reduce((acc,{Division,['Data Name']:Name,KPI}) => {
      // destructure Division 'Data Name' and KPI properties

      // destructure Names and KPIs Set()s
      const [,Names,KPIs] =
        acc[Division] = acc[Division] || [Division,new Set(),new Set()]
        // add to object map with key: [Division] and Set()s for Names and KPIs
      Names.add(Name)
      KPIs.add(KPI)
      return acc
    },{})
   // map Names Set() and KPIs Set() to .size count (number of occurrences)
   ).map(([div,names,kpis])=>([div,names.size,kpis.size]))
```

Comment: Using a Set is much cleaner than checking if the ``.indexOf() == -1``  up-voted.